Zentitle and Salesforce
Has anyone used REST with Zentitle?  I'm having a problem authenticating.  They give some examples in Java, but apparently I'm failing with converting them to Apex...
This is the example code I'm trying to convert to Apex. When I try to convert to Apex I get a 405 error. The endpoint I'm using is what the vendor specified as the oauth end point.
var body = 'grant_type=client_credentials'
            + '&client_id=' + clientId
            + '&client_secret=' + clientSecret;
pm.sendRequest({
    url: oauth_url,
    method: 'POST',
    header: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    },
    body: {
        mode: 'raw',
        raw: body
    }
}, function (err, res) {
    var response = res.json();
    environment.set("access_token", response.access_token);
    environment.set("token_time", Date.now() + response.expires_in * 1000);
});

=================================================================
    private static final String CLIENT_ID = 'xxxxxxxx';
    private static final String CLIENT_SECRET = 'xxxxxxx';
    private static final String USERNAME = 'shawn.xx@xx.com';
    private static final String PASSWORD = 'xxxxxxxxxx!';
    private static final String TOKEN_URL = 'xxxxxxx';
//

        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint(TOKEN_URL);
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

        String requestBody = 'grant_type=client_credentials' +
                             '&client_id=' + CLIENT_ID +
                             '&client_secret=' + CLIENT_SECRET +
                             '&username=' + USERNAME +
                             '&password=' + PASSWORD;

        req.setBody(requestBody);

        Http http = new Http();
        HttpResponse res = http.send(req);

        if (res.getStatusCode() == 200) {
            Map<String, Object> responseMap = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
            String accessToken = (String) responseMap.get('access_token');
            //return accessToken;
        } else {
            System.debug('Authentication failed. Status code: ' + res.getStatusCode() + ', Body: ' + res.getBody());
            //return null;
        }


Probably not (at least among people who are active here), and please [edit] your question to show us the example they give, your attempt to convert it to Apex, and any error messages that you're getting (verbatim).

That's the example they provided (in Javascript, Javascript != Java). You still need to include your attempt to translate it into Apex.

Sorry.  Here's one of the incarnations.  All very similar.  The log entries for what I've tried are the same.  I'm sure I'm missing something simple.  REST and Apex are both new to me.
14:35:32.1 (392112845)|CALLOUT_RESPONSE|[23]|System.HttpResponse[Status=Method Not Allowed, StatusCode=405]
14:35:32.1 (392153356)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[23]|Bytes:1623
14:35:32.1 (392268587)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[23]|res|"System.HttpResponse[Status=Method Not Allowed, StatusCode=405]"|0x66cb40f6

The example given by zentitle doesn't include the username and password, so try removing those. Your username definitely contains characters that are not url-safe (i.e. the @ in the email, and this is a problem because using x-www-form-urlencoded means that data must be url-safe), and your password might include some chars that aren't url-safe. The Client Credentials flow doesn't use a specific user like the Authorization Code flow does.

The username has an @ in it.  The other only other special characters are the _ in the username and a ! in the password.  I provided the log entry in one of my messages.  Would the 405 error play into what you're suspecting?

"Method not allowed" very specifically means you're trying to POST to an endpoint that doesn't accept that verb. Double check the documentation for the correct endpoint.

Thanks...  I figured that's what it meant, REST is new, so I didn't know if a malformed request would cause that.  I'm using the endpoint provided by the vendor.  I've got a message into them right now.  Thanks...

The above incarnation was one of my many attempts before reaching out.  I touched base with the vendor and the url provided was not correct.  Putting the correct url into one of my earlier versions authenticated as expected.  Thanks for the feedback folks...
